# how to arrange the location of the buttons become responsive

Tags: vb.net, forms, vb.net-2010

I have 10 buttons that are arranged parallel to the right. When in the windows form I change the size is smaller, then the zoom button is truncated by the form directly under the existing leftmost button. How to create it?
I've been setting anchor and dock, but did not find what I want

Comment: You might look at the `FlowLayoutPanel` control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the buttons in a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` are your best bets for this.